# DevExpress HtmlEditor not working as excepted

Tags: asp.net-mvc, devexpress

[image]

The buttons are not working and all the features are also not working.Sample picture is posted below.

Comment: Do you get any kind of script error when you load the control or when you press one of the toolbar buttons?

Comment: Open browser console window, edit your post to include either ReferenceError or TypeError you have seen there, including your HtmlEditor code (ASPX/Razor).